# loop in directories whose names are consecutive numbers

Tags: python, linux, directory

I have around 20 directories that I want to loop in. The directories are named:

```
00001 00002 00003 ... 00010 00011 ... 00020
```

How can I do that in `python`?

I tried the following:

```
import os

init = str('00001')
path = os.getcwd()

newpath = path + '/' + init
os.chdir(newpath)
print os.getcwd()
... # read and append data

# the next step would be to go to directory 00002. Then read and append data
# I will do the same thing in each directory
```

So far till here it worked, I was able to go to the first directory. But how can I do that for `n` directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it is the following:

```
# get the name of all directories starting with 00
dirs = glob.glob('00*')
path = os.getcwd()

for directory in dirs:
    newpath = path + '/' + directory
    os.chdir(newpath)
    # read and append data
```

Someone posted the answer but it seems that is has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the list of directory names and loop over them, like so:

```
import os

n = 20

dirs = [str(i).zfill(5) for i in xrange(n)]
path = os.getcwd()

for directory in dirs:
    newpath = os.path.join(path, directory)
    os.chdir(newpath)
    # read and append data
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One is

```
import os
os.chdir("whereever/they/are")
folders = ("{:05}".format(n) for n in range(21))
for folder in folders:
    files = os.listdir(folder)
    # do whatever you want
```

Another way is to do is use `os.walk`